# Ignore a git submodule only acessible over VPN

Tags: git, git-submodules

I'm working a project under git revision control that is not my project, but I have r/w access to it.  So, I can change what is under revision control in regards to the .gitmodules file, but risk committing the change to the git repository.

It has two git submodules listed in .gitmodules file, one of which is *only* accessible via a VPN, and the other is accessible over the public Internet.

I will not have access to the VPN network when updating my submodules after the initial pull via:

```
git submodule update
```

The pull will fail:

```
$ git submodule update
Cloning into subproject...
ssh: connect to host blah.example.com port 22: Connection refused
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
Clone of 'git@blah.exampl.ecom:project/subproject.git' into submodule path 'subproject' failed
```

Nor will I have access anytime afterward.

I don't want to have modify the .gitmodules file stripping out the offending submodule and risk committing my version of the file at later date, nor do I want to globally ignore .gitmodules files.

What I'd like to do is some how ignore this submodule, while still pulling down the submodule accessible on the open Internet, do my work, and commit my changes.  How do I do that with in the constraints I ticked off?